# Could not initialize class com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockApp

Tags: java-11, powermock, wiremock, wiremock-standalone, powermockrunner

I recently upgraded my Java version to Java11 for 8 and since then i am seeing this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockApp
>
> at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.(WireMockServer.java:73)
> at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.(WireMockServer.java:112)

Below you can find my usage of wiremock:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ConfigManagement.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*","com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*","com.github.tomakehurst.*"})
public class MandateEventsJobTest {

    private static HikariDataSource dataSource;
    private WireMockServer wireMockServer;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(8080);
        wireMockServer.start();
        stubFor(get(urlPathMatching("/ping")).willReturn(aResponse().withBody("pong")));

...
```

I'm not able to resolve this issue. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there's an issue with PowerMockRunner in java version 9 or above. I added even more packages to `@PowerMockIgnore({})` and it worked:

> @PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*","com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.*", "javax.net.*"})